# How to connect a lot of excel with python (like having a database)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, database

i need your help please in python
My problem is that i have a lot of excel table and i need to modify values in the one of them from the other table like this :

TABLE 1 :

CODE   OLDNOUN   COLUMN3  COLUMN4 .... COLUMNX

1       AZE
2       QSD
3       WXC

TABLE 2 :

CODE   NEWNOUN   ATTRIBUT

1       ABC        A1
2       DEF        B4
3       GHI        C2

MYFINAL TABLE SHOUD be like that :

CODE   OLDNOUN   COLUMN3  COLUMN4 .... COLUMNX ATTRIBUT

1       ABC                                        A1
2       DEF                                        B4
3       GHI                                        C2

In code it's like that :
IF TABLE_1.CODE == TABLE_2.CODE then TABLE_1.OLDNOUN = TABLE2_NEWNOUN
and to create the new column.

I don't know how to do it in python and thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with Excel in python by using openpyxl library. This link right here will help you get quickly started with the stuff you need to know in order to be able to do whatever you want to.

Link: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you Cray for feedback. I'll try to extract essential parts from the link whenever I am off work.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer i'll try it even if i'm really bad at python